# How to count all the clicked radio buttons when clicking submit then the scores will go to the database

Tags: javascript, php

How to count all the clicked radio buttons when clicking submit then the scores will go to the database

then score modal will fetch the score that's in the database. how to do that it is said that I should use

JQuery, should i really use it?

The value of the 4 radio buttons is 3 wrongs and 1 correct how to count all the radio buttons with correct value when it is clicked.

The HTML,JS and PHP is below

```
<?php
$Ans1 = $_POST['1'];
$Ans2 = $_POST['2'];
$Ans3 = $_POST['3'];
$Ans4 = $_POST['4'];
$Ans5 = $_POST['5'];
$Ans6 = $_POST['6'];
$Ans7 = $_POST['7'];
$Ans8 = $_POST['8'];
$Ans9 = $_POST['9'];
$Ans10 = $_POST['10'];

$Ans1 = $_POST['1'];

$INSERT = "INSERT Into scores(score) values (?)" ;



?>

<!-- PHP CODE FOR QUESTIONS AND ANSWERS   -->

<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questions WHERE B = 'I have 27 years'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


$Quest1 = $row[0];



?>
<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE B = 'I have 27 years'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);



$RDO1a = $row[1];
$RDO2a = $row[3];
$RDO3a = $row[2];
$RDO4a = $row[4];

?>



<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questions WHERE B = 'By Taxi' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$Quest2 = $row[0];


?>


<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE B = 'By Taxi' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$RDO1b = $row[1];
$RDO2b = $row[2];
$RDO3b = $row[3];
$RDO4b = $row[4];


?>



<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questions WHERE B = 'At least 7 years' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Quest3 = $row[0];

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE B = 'At least 7 years' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$RDO1c = $row[1];
$RDO2c = $row[2];
$RDO3c = $row[3];
$RDO4c = $row[4];


?>



<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questions WHERE B = 'some' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Quest4 = $row[0];

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE B = 'some' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$RDO1d = $row[1];
$RDO2d = $row[2];
$RDO3d = $row[3];
$RDO4d = $row[4];


?>



<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questions WHERE B = 'goes to' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Quest5 = $row[0];

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE B = 'goes to' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$RDO1e = $row[1];
$RDO2e = $row[2];
$RDO3e = $row[3];
$RDO4e = $row[4];

?>



<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questions WHERE B = 'in Wednesdays' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Quest6 = $row[0];

?>


<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE B = 'in Wednesdays' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


$RDO1f = $row[1];
$RDO2f = $row[2];
$RDO3f = $row[3];
$RDO4f = $row[4];

?>


<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questions WHERE B = 'Do you like?' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Quest7 = $row[0];

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE B = 'Do you like?' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


$RDO1g = $row[1];
$RDO2g = $row[2];
$RDO3g = $row[3];
$RDO4g = $row[4];


?>


<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questions WHERE B = 'one white' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Quest8 = $row[0];

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE B = 'one white' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$RDO1h = $row[1];
$RDO2h = $row[2];
$RDO3h= $row[3];
$RDO4h = $row[4];


?>




<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questions WHERE B = 'has' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Quest9 = $row[0];

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE B = 'has' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$RDO1i = $row[1];
$RDO2i = $row[2];
$RDO3i= $row[3];
$RDO4i = $row[4];

?>



<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questions WHERE B = 'brothers or sisters' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$Quest10 = $row[0];

?>

<?php

$sql = "SELECT * FROM questions WHERE B = 'brothers or sisters' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

$RDO1j = $row[1];
$RDO2j = $row[2];
$RDO3j= $row[3];
$RDO4j = $row[4];

?>

<div id = english>

<div class = "Top" > 
        <h3> COLLEGE ENTRANCE EXAMINATION </h3>

<div class = "Question">

    <h3 class = "Instruction"> <i> INSTRUCTION: Choose the right answer from the multiple choices. </h3> </i> </h3>
<center>    <h2> ENGLISH  </h2> </center>
    <center>     <table border = '0' style = "width: 70%">  </center>
    <hr> </hr>
<tr>
    <h3> <?php echo "1." . $Quest1; ?> </h3> 
    <td> <h4> <label class="container"> <?php echo $RDO1a; ?>
         <input type="radio" name="1">
    <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
    </label> </td> </h4>

     <td> <h4> <label class="container"> <?php echo $RDO3a; ?>
    <input type="radio" name="1">
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label> </td> </h4>
</tr>
    <tr> 
        <td> <h4> <label class="container"> <?php echo $RDO2a; ?>
         <input type="radio" name="1">
    <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
    </label> </td> </h4>

 <td> <h4> <label class="container"> <?php echo $RDO4a; ?>
    <input type="radio" name="1">
     <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label> </td> </h4>
</tr>
    </table>


    <center> <table border = '0' style = "width: 70%"> </center>
    <hr>
    <tr>
         <h3> <?php echo "2." . $Quest2; ?> </h3> 
         <td> <h4> <label class = "container">  <?php echo $RDO1b; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="2">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>

         <td> <h4> <label class="container">  <?php echo $RDO2b; ?>
            <input type = "radio" name="2">
            <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
            </label> </td> </h4>
        </tr>
    <tr>
         <td> <h4> <label class="container">  <?php echo $RDO3b; ?>
            <input type = "radio" name="2">
            <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
            </label> </td> </h4>

         <td> <h4> <label class="container">  <?php echo $RDO4b; ?>
            <input type = "radio" name="2">
            <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
            </label> </td>  </h4>
    </tr>
</table>
<center> <table border = '0'  style = "width: 70%"> </center>

    <hr>
<tr>
         <h3> <?php echo "3." . $Quest3; ?> </h3> 
         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO1c; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="3">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO2c; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="3">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>
</tr>
    <tr>    
         <td> <h4> <label class = "container">  <?php echo $RDO3c; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="3">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container">  <?php echo $RDO4c; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="3">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>
</tr>
</table> 


<center> <table border = '0' style = "width: 70%"> </center>
    <hr>
<tr>
         <h3> <?php echo "4." . $Quest4; ?> </h3> 

     <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO1d; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="4">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>

 <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO2d; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="4">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>
</tr>

        <tr>
            <td> <h4> <label class = "container"><?php echo $RDO3d; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="4">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>

            <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO4d; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="4">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4> 
</tr>
    </table>

<center> <table border = '0' style = "width: 70%"> </center>
    <hr>
<tr>
         <h3> <?php echo "5." . $Quest5; ?> </h3> 

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO1e; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="5">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO2e; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="5">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO3e; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="5">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO4e; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="5">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>
</tr>
</table> 



<center> <table border = '0' style = "width: 70%"> </center>
    <hr>
<tr>
         <h3> <?php echo "6." . $Quest6; ?> </h3> 

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO1f; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="6">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO2f; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="6">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>
    </tr>
    <tr>
         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO3f; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="6">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO4f; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="6">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>
    </tr>
</table>


<center> <table border = '0' style = "width: 70%"> </center>
    <hr>
<tr>

         <h3> <?php echo "7." . $Quest7; ?> </h3> 

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO1g; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="7">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO2g; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="7">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>
    </tr>
    <tr>

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO3g; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="7">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </h4>
        </label> </td> </h4>

         <td>  <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO4g; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="7">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </hr>
        </label> </td> </h4>


<center> <table border = '0' style = "width: 70%"> </center>
    <hr>
<tr>
         <h3> <?php echo "8." . $Quest8; ?> </h3> 

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO1h; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="8">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </h4>
        </label> </td> </h4>

        <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO2h; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="8">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </h4>
        </label> </td> </h4>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO3h; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="8">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </h4>
        </label> </td> </h4>

        <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO4h; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="8">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </h4>
        </label> </td> </h4>
</tr>
</table>

<center> <table border = '0' style = "width: 70%"> </center>
    <hr>
<tr>
         <h3><?php echo "9." . $Quest9; ?> </h3> 

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container">  <?php echo $RDO1i; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="9">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </h4>
        </label> </td> </h4>

        <td> <h4> <label class = "container">  <?php echo $RDO2i; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="9">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </h4>
        </label> </td> </h4>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO3i; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="9">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> </h4>
        </label> </td> </h4>

        <td> <h4> <label class = "container">  <?php echo $RDO4i; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="9">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> 
        </label> </h4> </td> </tr>
</table> 


<center> <table border = '0' style = "width: 70%"> </center>
    <hr>
<tr>
         <h3> <?php echo "10." . $Quest10; ?> </h3> 

         <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO1j; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="10">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> 
        </label> </h4> </td>

        <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO2j; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="10">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> 
        </label> </h4> </td> </tr>

        <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO3j; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="10">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> 
        </label> </h4> </td>

        <td> <h4> <label class = "container"> <?php echo $RDO4j; ?>
        <input type = "radio" name="10">
        <span class="checkmark"></span> 
        </label> </h4> </td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
<?php

$sql = "SELECT QUESTIONS FROM questionsmath WHERE B = '-5'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


$Quest1M = $row[0];



?>

<script>
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
var modalLast = document.getElementById("myModalLast");
var btn = document.getElementById("submit");
var btnYes = document.getElementById("yes");
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modalLast.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
no.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
btnYes.onclick = function() {
  modalLast.style.display = "block";
  modal.style.display = "none";
}
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  else if (event.target == modalLast){
    modalLast.style.display = "false";
  }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are considering javascript to count the correct answers, then you are basically letting the client browser "know" the correct answers beforehand. That can lead to cheating.

Comment: so what should i use?

Comment: use AJAX, onSubmit send the answers to a `php` file. check the answers there and send back the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should post only the code that matters to the question. Posting the complete php/js code will only distract us and prevent people from finding the problem and helping.

Saying that, and as I pointed out in my comment to your question, if you don't mind letting javascript "know" which answers are correct and which are wrong, then you can just simply give the correct answers a class, like `correct` and later when the form is submitted, you can do a count of all radio buttons that were checked and are marked as correct behind the scenes.

I am not sure why you would want to do it on the client side, since the HTML markup code can be inspected, and people can know which answers are correct. But if that is not a concern to you, then here is one way to achieve it:

```js
document.getElementById("btn-check").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let numberOfCorrectAnswers = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=radio].correct:checked").length;
  console.log("Correct Answers: " + numberOfCorrectAnswers);
});
```

```css
.question {
  display: block;
  color: navy;
  background-color: #def;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <div class='question'>What is the sum of 11+33?</div>
  <label><input class='wrong' type='radio' name='q1' />45</label><br />
  <label><input class='correct' type='radio' name='q1' />44</label><br />
  <label><input class='wrong' type='radio' name='q1' />47</label><br />
  <label><input class='wrong' type='radio' name='q1' />42</label>
</p>

<p>
  <div class='question'>What is the sum of 3+5?</div>
  <label><input class='wrong' type='radio' name='q2' />2</label><br />
  <label><input class='wrong' type='radio' name='q2' />4</label><br />
  <label><input class='wrong' type='radio' name='q2' />6</label><br />
  <label><input class='correct' type='radio' name='q2' />8</label>
</p>

<button id='btn-check'>Check Number of Correct Answers</button>
```